# Disable "Print and Close" Preview Shortcut on OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.2)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-mountain-lion, preview

I recently upgraded to Mountain Lion from Leopard and there is a global shortcut that I would really like to disable.

Apparently, now if you select a document and press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>, Preview will open, print the document, then close.

I'm sure this was done with the purest intentions but, unfortunately, it is right next to <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>, which I use many times a day to open files.  Since installing Mountain Lion, I've accidentally printed way too many documents just trying to open them!

I've gone into the Keyboard preference pane and tried to find where this shortcut is located, but haven't had any success.  Anyone know how I can disable this?